# Алгоритм разбиения дерева на компоненты связности

Tags: алгоритм, графы, дерево

Есть дерево, в котором каждая вершина имеет свой вес, нужно разбить дерево на три компоненты связности, в каждой из которых суммарный вес всех вершин одинаков.

Подскажите, какой алгоритм стоит использовать?

Пока вижу такое решение - перебор всех пар ребер, с последующей проверкой - но это тяжелое решение по производительности.

Comment: Эта задача у Вас возникла всё по той же теме: оценка размера PNG (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649761/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-png-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/651646#651646) ?

Comment: Что делать, если решения не существует? Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно удалить какие-то 2 ребра? В таком случае в дереве окажется 3 компоненты связности. Каков размер дерева?

Comment: @hedgehogues, нет, задачи не связаны друг с другом, в случае отсутствия решения просто сообщить об этом (ведь на самом деле его может и не быть) набор данных ограничен только тем, что граф это любое дерево (для простоты полагается что как минимум два ребра есть)

Comment: В таких задачах правильное решение и выбор алгоритма **критически** зависит от того, могут ли веса вершин быть отрицательными. В том числе и в этой задаче. Могут или нет?

Comment: На три связных компоненты, а не на 3 компоненты связности.

Comment: @Ant, нет не могут быть отрицательными

Comment: А нулевыми могут?

Comment: @Ant, нет - (хотя наверное и этот случай легко обрабатывается (нулевые просто пропускаются в процессе обработки)

Comment: Просто если все веса строго положительны, то разбиение (если оно существует) будет однозначным. А если есть нулевые веса, то могут появляться компоненты нулевого веса, которые можно будет гонять туда-сюда. Т.е. появляется неоднозначность в решении. Однозначная задача более "осязаема".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ясно, что для выполнения разбиения надо удалить ровно два ребра. Ясно также, что каждая компонента будет деревом. Также заранее ясно, чему будет равен суммарный вес вершин в каждом из трех поддеревьев. Пусть это будет S<sub>target</sub>.

Обозначим любую вершину дерева корнем и далее рассматриваем *корневое* дерево.

- Будем строить наши связные компоненты путем наращивания (и объединения) множества поддеревьев снизу-вверх, от листьев к корню. Начинаем с набора стартовых поддеревьев, каждое из которых состоит из одной листовой вершины дерева.
- Если на каком-то этапе построения мы обнаруживаем поддерево T с суммой S<sub>target</sub>, то существует решение, включающее поддерево T (если у задачи вообще есть решение). Все остальные варианты разбиения могут лишь "наращивать" T дополнительными вершинами, суммарный вес которых равен нулю. Будем назвать поддерево с суммой S<sub>target</sub> *завершенным*.
- Рассмотрим незавершенное поддерево T, корневая вершина которого являются сыном вершины P. Ясно, что P должно входить в одну и ту же связную компоненту, что и T.
- Из последнего утверждения сразу следует, что если у нас есть несколько незавершенных поддеревьев, корневые вершины которых являются сыновьями одного и того же предка P, то все они должны входить в одну и ту же связную компоненту, включающую также и P.

Отсюда автоматически следует, что решение задачи достаточно тривиально:

1. Начинаем с набора стартовых поддеревьев T, каждое из которых состоит из одной листовой вершины дерева.
2. Циклически обрабатываем текущий набор поддеревьев T, пока у нас не останется ровно одно поддерево:
3. Если суммарный вес какого-то поддерева строго равен S<sub>target</sub> (завершенное поддерево), то считаем его частью результата и исключаем из дальнейшего рассмотрения (исключаем из T и условно исключаем из исходного дерева).
4. Если в процессе такого исключения какая-то вершина исходного дерева становится листовой, то добавляем ее в T как отдельное поддерево.
5. Если у нас в T присутствуют *все незавершенные поддеревья*, чьи корни являются сыновьями некоей вершины P, то объединяем их в одно поддерево с корнем P.
6. По завершению работы цикла 2-5 мы получим набор связных компонент, полученных на шаге 3, а также единственное оставшееся поддерево в T.
7. Если на шаге 3 получено ровно 2 завершенных поддерева, а вес оставшегося поддерева в T тоже равен S<sub>target</sub> - то это наше решение.
8. Если на шаге 3 получено ровно 3 завершенных поддерева, а вес оставшегося поддерева в T равен нулю - то объединяем оставшееся поддерево с любым из завершенных и получаем решение.
9. В противном случае задача решения не имеет.

Comment: У меня примерно такие мысли и были - решение задачи за линейный проход

Comment: Только идея у меня такая была - сгруппировать узлы дерева по глубине, затем процессить с самых глубоких до корня. На каждом шаге для каждого узла заданной глубины идти к родительскому + накапливать суммарный вес. При каждой обработки либо мержить, либо находить компоненты связности

Answer (score 4):

Задачка, кажущаяся на первой взгляд, переборной со сложностью [image: сложность лобового алгоритма] (N -- число вершин), может быть решена проще, быстрее, за полиномиальное время. Почему это так я хочу описать ниже.

Во-первых, кажущийся переборный алгоритм имеет место для произвольного графа (возможно есть оптимизации и можно решить быстрее). У нас же граф очень специфический. Он намного проще того, что есть в общем случае. Эта простота, например, выражается в отсутствии циклов.

Во-вторых, нам нужно разбить наш граф всего на 3 компоненты связности.

Теперь давайте обсудим: как это разбивать граф на компоненты связности. Мы сразу скажем, что разбиение на компоненты связности -- это удаление некоторых рёбер. Приведу пример разбиения на компоненты связности следующего графа:

[image: Исходный граф]

Получим 2 компоненты связности:

[image: 2 компоненты связности -- 1]

Получим 3 компоненты связности:

[image: 3 компоненты связности -- 1]

Другой пример. Получим 2 компоненты связности (вершина 1 -- это заменена на вершину 15):

[image: 2 компоненты связности -- 2]

Получим 3 компоненты связности:

[image: 3 компоненты связности -- 2]

Как можно наблюдать, всегда при удалении **1 ребра**, появляется ещё одна компонента связности. Это можно доказать срого. Но воздержимся, дабы не загружать текст. Таким образом, нужно удалить **2 ребра** так, чтобы у нас оказалось **3 компоненты связности**.

Давайте немного переформулируем задачу. Нам необходимо поставить 2 метки на рёбра так, чтобы в каждой компоненте оказался суммарный вес одинаковым. Что же для этого нужно сделать? ОЧЕВИДНО! Перебрать все пары рёбер. Для этого занумеруем их от **0** до **N-1**. Переберём все пары рёбер. И для каждой пары будем проверять: правильное ли у нас разбиение или нет. Напишем псевдокод:

```
# Перебираем все рёбра
for i in range edge:
    for j in range edge:
       # Если разбиение делит наше дерево на равные по весу части, то заканчиваем выполнение
       if Splitting(i, j):
           break
```

Очевидно, что сложность такого алгоритма будет полиномиальной

[image: O(N^2 * g(N))],

где **g(n)** -- время работы `Splitting`.

Но что делаь с функцией `Splitting(i, j)`? Очевидно, что `Splitting(i, j)` может отработать за линейное время. Запустим из каждой вершины [обход в глубину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83), причём, если в некоторой вершине мы уже были, то не будем туда заходить больше. Вот и получится, что мы обошли все вершины лишь по одному разу. Т.е. мы обошли каждую компоненту связности единожды. В таком случае, ассимптотическое время работы будет [image: сложность O(N)], хотя, по факту, это будет **2N**. Внутри **DFS** (обход в глубину) мы будем считать веса для каждой компоненты связности.

Время работы `Splitting` можно улучшить следующим образом. Сделаем для этого предподсчёт. Для каждого ребра будем хранить 2 параметра: суммарный вес вершин выше ребра и суммарный вес ниже ребра. Приведём пример:

[image: Пример кластеризации]

Т.е. для ребра, соединяющего вершины **15** (она же 1, см. выше) и **3**, мы можем посчитать суммарный вес в каждом кластере. Делать это будем следующим образом. Запустим [LR-обход](http://algolist.manual.ru/ds/walk.php) дерева и для каждого ребра (Замечу, что рёбра можно ассоциировать с соответствующими вершинами. Например, ребро **(11, 10)** ассоциируем с вершиной **11**, ребро **(6, 2)** ассоциируем с вершиной 6 и т.д. Далее будем говорить о вершинах, а не о рёбрах).

Продемонстрируем пример обхода:

```
0 - 10 - 11 - 12 - 13 - 15 (1) - 3 - 4 - 5 - 9 - 2 - 6 - 7 - 8
```

При обходе будем суммировать считать вес поддерева. Под весом поддерева будем разуметь сумму всех вершин. Пусть на **i**-ом шаге мы уже подсчитали вес поддерева с корнем в вершине **v**. Тогда нам необходимо перейти на уровень выше и посчитать вес поддерева более высокого уровня. Проиллюстрируем на рисунке ниже.

[image: Иллюстрация к подсчёту веса поддерева]

Пусть мы находимся в вершине **11**. И для поддерева этой вершины мы уже посчитали вес (на рисунке она изображена листом, но будем считать, что у неё есть поддерево). Тогда нам необходимо перейти в вершину **10** и подсчитать вес поддерева вершины **10**. В порядке **LR-обхода**, посетим и подсчитаем вес поддерева с корнем в вершине **12**, **13**. Тогда вес поддерева с корнем в вершине **10**, будет суммой весов поддеревьев **11**, **12**, **13**:

[image: Формула для вычисления веса поддерева рекурсивно на примере]

Имеем формулу в общем случае:

[image: Формула для вычисления веса поддерева рекурсивно в общем случае]

Для вершины **v** обозначим вес дерева выше неё:

[image: Вес дерева выше вершины]

ниже неё:

[image: Вес дерева ниже вершины]

Теперь, нам нужно вычислить аналогично, для каждой вершины вес дерева выше неё. Для этого будем считать, что выше корневой вершины ничего нет. Тогда ещё раз запустим **LR-обход (модифицированный)**. Модификация будет состоять в том, что мы будем осуществлять все действия ещё при спуске.

Очевидно, что данный алгоритм вычисления вышеуказанных характеристик отработает за время [image: Ассимптотика].

Таким образом, для каждой вершины имеем вес дерева ниже неё и вес дерева выше неё.

Теперь нам необходимо научиться быстро узнавать: лежит ли данная вершина **v** в поддереве другой вершины **u**. Введём функцию:

[image: Функция]

Для её быстрого вычисления нам понадобятся дополнительные ухищрения. И ещё один предподсчёт.

Comment: ваше решение как раз то о чем я написал обычный метод грубой силы (правда немного не возьму в толк откуда у вас 2^N сложность выскочила, на первый взгляд не могу представить такой сложный алгоритм)

Comment: @LmTinyToon В чём моё решение грубой силой? Оно работает за куб. Разве это очень плохо? Я могу ускорить его до квадрата. 2^N -- это в том случае, если осуществлять перебор по всем маскам рёбер. Т.е. 111111 -- все рёбра есть. 1011111 -- нет ребра #2. Проверяем, подходит ли данное решение или нет. И т.д. Перебрав все маски, получим ответ.

Comment: За сколько Вы хотите решить эту задачу? Думаю, что быстрее чем за O(NlogN) не получится. Возможно, выйдет за O(N) с предподсчётом в виде O(N) или O(N^2)

Comment: ну грубая сила (в моем понимании) потому, что выполняете полный перебор вариантов. Конечно решение за N^3 тоже подойдет, просто знаете, иногда хочется найти очень красивое решение  - может существует уже какой-то известный результат подобной проблемы

Comment: @LmTinyToon, Вы тогда оговаривайте, что есть грубая сила в Вашем понимании. Хорошо, допишу решение за O(N^2). Вероятно, я могу его сделать. В таком случае, предлагайте своё решение, а не пишите вопрос, как сделали это Вы: у меня есть задача, хочу алгоритм.

Comment: ну насчет алгоритма я оговорился сразу (привел его краткое описание) - просто подумал может найдется более производительный алгоритм, тот же N^2 или O (N log N)

Comment: @LmTinyTool, Алгоритм `O(1)` для `Splitting` я придумал. Завтра продемонстрирую.

Comment: у меня есть мысли о линейном алгоритме, прежде чем описывать хочу реализовать посмотреть его

Comment: @LmTinyToon Линейный? Ну, не знаю. Нужно что-то магическое с рёбрами делать. Несколько сомневаюсь.